# Recursion Problem - breaking long sentence in multiple short strings

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to take a string and break it into small chunks if it is over certain number of words.
I keep on getting a RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

What in my code is making this happen?

```
import math

# Shorten Sentence into small pieces
def shorten(sentenceN):

  # If it is a string - and length over 6 - then shorten recursively
  if (isinstance(sentenceN, str)):
    sentence = sentenceN.split(' ')
    array = []
    length = len(sentenceN)
    halfed = math.floor(length / 2)

    if length < 6:
      return [sentenceN]

    # If sentence is long - break into two parts then rerun shorten on each part
    else:
      first = shorten(" ".join(sentence[:halfed]))
      second = shorten(" ".join(sentence[halfed:]))
      array.append(first)
      array.append(second)
      return array

  # If the object is an array (sentence is already broken up) - run shorten on each - append 
  # result to array for returning

  if(isinstance(sentenceN, list)):
    array = []
    for sentence in sentenceN:
      array.append(shorten(sentence))
    return array

# example sentences to use 
longSentence = "On offering to help the blind man, the man who then stole his car, had not, at that precise moment."

shortSentence = "On offering to help the blind man."

shorten(shortSentence)
shorten(longSentence)
```

Comment: What are the expected outputs for your sentences?

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a recursive function in Python on a large input ( > 10^4), you might encounter a “maximum recursion depth exceeded error”. 
here you have recursion:

```
  first = shorten(" ".join(sentence[:halfed]))
  second = shorten(" ".join(sentence[halfed:]))
```

it means calling the same function over and over, it has to store in a stack to be returned in someplace, but it seems like your sentence is too long that stack is overflowing and hit maximum recursion depth.
you have to do something with the logic of the code like increase this 6 to a greater number

```
if length < 6:
  return [sentenceN]
```

or just increase recursion depth with

```
import sys 
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)
```